# Отсортировать словарь по определённому значению

Tags: python, сортировка, list, список

Мне нужно отсортировать словарь words по значению b, как это сделать не совсем понимаю.

```
i = 0
    words = {}
    res = txt.get()
    with open('word_search.csv', newline='') as File:
        reader = csv.reader(File)
        for row in reader:
            b = fuzz.WRatio(res, row)
            if b >= 75:
                words[i] = [b, row]
                i += 1
    sorted(words,reverse=True)
    for row in words:
        print(words[row])
```

Входное слово: `googl`

Пример вывода:

```
[90, ['go']]
[90, ['l']]
[90, ['o']]
[90, ['g']]
[91, ['google']]
[90, ['oo']]
[90, ['gl']]
[90, ['og']]
[90, ['goo']]
[89, ['goog']]
[90, ['googlebot']]
[75, ['gol']]
[90, ['googling']]
[83, ['googled']]
```

Comment: b это расстояние между строками. Мне нужно отсортировать словарь words по b.

Comment: Дополните вопрос примерами входных данных и результата, пожалуйста.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, дополнил.

Comment: Как должен быть отсортирован вывод? Из вашего примера непонятно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy по значению слева от слова в списке выше всех должно быть слово google со значением 91

Comment: Приведите пример вывода в соответствие с задачей, пожалуйста.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ниже показано как нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не сразу понял, что у вас словарь, плюс ключи словаря - просто порядковые номера в списке, а не рейтинг. Вы не запоминаете никуда результат сортировки, а кроме того у вас сортировка идёт по ключу словаря, где нет нужной для сортировки информации. Можно сделать так:

```
for k,v in sorted(words.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0], reverse=True):
    print(v[0], v[1])
```

Вывод:

```
91 ['google']
90 ['l']
90 ['o']
90 ['g']
90 ['oo']
90 ['gl']
90 ['og']
90 ['goo']
90 ['googlebot']
90 ['googling']
89 ['goog']
83 ['googled']
75 ['gol']
```

Пояснения:

- итерация по словарю равнозначна итерации по его ключам `.keys()`, поэтому нужно использовать `.items()`, чтобы у `sorted` была полная информация об элементах словаря, а не только ключ, котором только порядковый номер элемента
- содержимое элементов при этом получается такое примерно: `(0, [90, ['l']])`, т.е. список в кортеже, и чтобы достать оттуда рейтинг нужно взять элемент 1 из кортежа, чтобы получить список, и потом взять элемент 0 этого списка

В целом вы не очень правильно используете словарь, у вас фактически получился аналог списка, к списку точно так же можно обращаться по порядковым номерам элементов, большого смысла в таком словаре нет. Имело бы больше смысла сделать словарь, ключом которого было бы значение рейтинга, а значением - список слов, у которых такой рейтинг. Тогда сортировку можно было бы делать как-раз таки просто по ключам словаря.

Comment: При варианте sort у меня ошибка. Пробовал с ним поэтому и писал sorted.

Comment: `words` не список а словарь.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Сразу не заметил

Comment: @CrazyElf
[90, ['go']]
[90, ['l']]
[90, ['o']]
[90, ['g']]
[91, ['google']]
[90, ['oo']]
[90, ['gl']]
[90, ['og']]
[90, ['goo']]
[89, ['goog']]
[90, ['googlebot']]
[75, ['gol']]
[90, ['googling']]
[83, ['googled']]
У меня такой вывод почему-то

Comment: @Jool Напечатайте ещё `row`, какие у вас в них значения, интересно. Подозреваю, что там не просто цифры. Добавьте `print(row)` внутрь цикла и покажите, что там.

Comment: @CrazyElf, [90, ['go']]
0
[90, ['l']]
1
[90, ['o']]
2
[90, ['g']]
3
[91, ['google']]
4
[90, ['oo']]
5
[90, ['gl']]
6
[90, ['og']]
7
[90, ['goo']]
8
[89, ['goog']]
9
[90, ['googlebot']]
10
[75, ['gol']]
11
[90, ['googling']]
12
[83, ['googled']]
13

Comment: @Jool А, ок, понял. Поменял код и описание

Comment: @CrazyElf, сработало. Постараюсь разобраться сейчас как это работает!

Comment: @Jool Добавил пояснения

Comment: `words.items()` -> `words.values()`

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy В принципе да, в данном случае ключи словаря вообще не нужны